# Vertical boxplot using chart.Boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, performanceanalytics

I'm not able to get `horizontal=FALSE` in `chart.Boxplot()` to produce a vertical plot:

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
z <- runif(1:100)
chart.Boxplot(z)
chart.Boxplot(z, horizontal=FALSE)
```

The two plots look the same.

This is with PerformanceAnalytics version 1.1.0 and R version 3.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a small bug. You should contact the maintainer. You should just replace the line ( in 2 places in the code)

```
boxplot(R[, column.order], horizontal = TRUE,..
```

By

```
boxplot(R[, column.order], horizontal = horizontal,...
```